# Deep copy (unbind) two scope variables - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to **have two separate variables** (`data.newPictures`, `profile.pictures`), one initialized with the values of the other.

Initialization runs well, but when I edit one runnig function `removeNewPicture($index)` **I edit also the second** one (like they're binded).

The **expected result** is the total independence of the two objects, so that  function only removes data from `data.newPictures`, keeping profile.pictures unchanged.

Any ideas how to prevent this?

```
app.controller('ModelController', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $models, $toast) {
$models.getModel($stateParams.uid)
    .then((model) => {
        $scope.profile = model;

        $scope.data = {
            edit: false,
            newPictures: $scope.profile.pictures, // <<< Initialization
            newBiography: $scope.profile.biography,
            newFeatures: $scope.profile.features,
            newStarting_fees: $scope.profile.starting_fees
        };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        $toast.error(err.err);
        if(err.code === 69) $state.go('login');
    });

  $scope.removeNewPicture = ($index) => {
    $scope.data.newPictures.splice($index, 1); // <<< This edits both the objects
    console.log($scope.data.newPictures, $scope.profile.pictures);
  };

  $scope.profile = {};
  $scope.data = {};
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picture and newPicture reference the same array. Create a copy to newPictures to avoid this issue

```
newPictures: angular.copy($scope.profile.pictures),
```

Comment: Used this, seems more "Angular" I guess haha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same object.

You should assign `newPictures` like `$scope.profile.pictures.slice(0);` in order to get the array copied.

Snippet would become:

```
$scope.data = {
            edit: false,
            newPictures: $scope.profile.pictures.slice(0),
            newBiography: $scope.profile.biography,
            newFeatures: $scope.profile.features,
            newStarting_fees: $scope.profile.starting_fees
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.data.newPictures` and `$scope.profile.pictures` refer the same object.
You should 'clone' the object you want to copy:

```
...
newPictures: jQuery.extend(true, {}, $scope.profile.pictures);
...
```